# member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type C#

Tags: c#

The code below is in C# and I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace FrontEnd
{
    class Flow
    {
        long i;
        private int x,y;
        public int X
        {
            get;set;
        }
        public int Y
        {
            get;set;
        }

        private void Flow()
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public void NaturalNumbers(int x, int y)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile the above code I get this error:

> Error: 'Flow': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Why? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Method names which are same as the class name are called *constructors*. Constructors do not have a return type. So correct as:

```
private Flow()
{
   X = x;
   Y = y;
}
```

Or rename the function as:

```
private void DoFlow()
{
   X = x;
   Y = y;
}
```

Though the whole code does not make any sense to me.

Comment: But where do (the values of) `x` and `y` come from ?

Comment: Note that this error can also happen if by mistake your class name and your xaml name are the same. Happened to me today.

Answer (score 28):

The problem is with the method:

```
private void Flow()
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
```

Your class is named `Flow` so this method can't also be named `Flow`. You will have to change the name of the `Flow` method to something else to make this code compile.

Or did you mean to create a private constructor to initialize your class? If that's the case, you will have to remove the `void` keyword to let the compiler know that your declaring a constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Constructors don't return a type , just remove the return type which is void in your case. It would run fine then.

Answer (score 4):

As Constructor should be at the starting of the Class , you are facing the above issue . So, you can either change the name or if you want to use it as a constructor just copy the method at the beginning of the class.

Answer (score 3):

just remove this because constructor don't have a return type like void
it will be like this :

```
private Flow()
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A constructor should no have a return type .
remove void before each constructor .

Some very basic characteristic of a constructor :

a. Same name as class
b. no return type.
c. will be called every time an object is made with the class. for eg- in your program if u made two objects   of Flow, 
Flow flow1=new Flow();
Flow flow2=new Flow();
 then Flow constructor will be called for 2 times.

d. If you want to call the constructor just for once then declare that as static (static constructor) and dont forget to remove any access modifier from static constructor ..