# What is the error "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type" means when creating a constructor, and how to solve it?

Tags: c#, class, oop, constructor, compiler-errors

When tring to create a constructor for a class from the same class name. 
Why does it throws an error saying as follows:

`" Error: 'StaveProcessor': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"`

Code :

```
namespace ImageProcessing
{
    class StaveProcessor
    {
        public Bitmap stave;

        public StaveProcessor(Bitmap image) //constructor
        {
            stave = image;
        }
    }
}
```

How to solve this and create the constructor?

*ps: Please consider my self not as an expert and excuse me for asking silly question if, and help me to learn and identify. Thank You*

Comment: There is no problem with this code, is this all the code ? I mean do you have other methods in it ?

Comment: Code compiles just fine. Did you try restarting your IDE? Take a look at the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750172/cant-create-class-constructor-getting-error-member-names-cannot-be-the-same-a?rq=1).

Comment: Your program seems ok. do you have any other StaveProcessor constructor in this class? the problem you mansion is occurred when you provide a return type to a constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the code that you've provided has no issues in it (it compiles), the exception you're getting would show if you did something like the following:

```
class StaveProcessor
{
    // can't have this method with this name (note the void, it's not a constructor)
    public void StaveProcessor(Bitmap image)
    {
        stave = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP show the constructor has no return type. so why you give this kind of answer. you should ask him first about this @ Dimitar Dimitrov

Comment: @Rezoan because this is a legitimate reason for the error that he's getting, he might not be providing all of his code, possibly he's having a method further down the lines that looks like this. It could be helpful for him, now he'd know what to look for. I hope I'm making sense. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

@hirosht your code haven't got any error: see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070701/member-names-cannot-be-the-same-as-their-enclosing-type-c-sharp) there was the same problem

Answer is(I think) you've declared your constructor with a type, like void or int or something else.