# Microsoft Report wizard cannot integrate in ASP.NET mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-create-RDLC-report-step-by-step-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) to create RDLC report in ASP.Net using C#

In my case I want to generate report in Report Wizard exactly like above example.then generate to report in different extensions.

**ReportViewer1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project_name.Report.ReportViewer1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 170px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:reportviewer id="ReportViewer1" runat="server" width="600"></rsweb:reportviewer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ReportViewer1.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System.Data;
using Project_name.Report;


namespace Project_name.Report
{
    public partial class ReportViewer1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
                DataSet dsCustomers = GetData("select top 20 * from AB_Products");
                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Project_nameDataSet", dsCustomers.Tables[0]);
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            }
        }

        private DataSet GetData(string query)
        {
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project_nameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dsCustomers, "DataTable1");
                        return dsCustomers;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I'm getting red squiggly line in following lines in **ReportViewer1.aspx.cs** file

```
   1. ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
   2. ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
   3. ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
   4. ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
```

When I hover over on above line its showing me following errors respectively

```
1.'ReportViewer1' does not contain definition for 'ProcessingMode'
2.'ReportViewer1' does not contain definition for 'LocalReport'
3.'ReportViewer1' does not contain definition for 'LocalReport'
4.'ReportViewer1' does not contain definition for 'LocalReport'
```

this is my folder hierarchy

[image]

What should I do to get this thing done. Is this problem occur due to wrong connectionstring ? or due to referring wrong data resource ?

Comment: This code is WebFoms, not MVC

Comment: So you're saying resource that I followed is not feasible for my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `web.config` file doesn't contain the necessary assembly references for the ReportViewer control.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

And you are most likely also missing the declaration of the control in your `ReportViewer1.aspx.designer.cs` file.

```
public partial class ReportViewer1 {

    /// <summary>
    /// form1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;

    /// <summary>
    /// ReportViewer1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer ReportViewer1;
}
```

But the simplest thing to do is to follow the right way to create a WebForm in the first place and then Visual Studio will add the references for you. First, add a web form to your MVC project.

1. Right click the project in solution explorer and go to Add > Web Form.
2. Give the form a descriptive name.

[image]

Then add the `ReportViewer` control.

1. Click on the Toolbox (typically on the left side of Visual Studio).
2. Open the `Reporting` expanding section.
3. Drag and drop the ReportViewer into the `<form>` tag on the page.

[image]

You will then have a form that looks something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MvcApplication11.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then you can add the code to the codebehind file (in this case it would be `WebForm1.aspx.cs`). You will be able to access the page at `/WebForm1.aspx`, but you can change the URL if you like using .NET routing.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx

Comment: Yeah! thats the way I followed here. but in my case I added web form in "Report" folder.

Error occur in my code-behind file actually which is ReportViewer1.aspx.cs file . So what did I do here different from your approach ?

Comment: You didn't select the ReportViewer from the toolbox, which would automatically add the necessary references to `web.config` and the `ReportViewer1.aspx.designer.cs` file.

Comment: once I create a web-form how to select a report viewer ? is that okay If I double click on report viewer option ?

Comment: I am using VS 2012. I tried double-clicking. It added the correct references, but did not add the ReportViewer1 control declaration. However, if you drag and drop the ReportViewer from the toolbox it will add the declaration as well.

Comment: Thnks lot, now those 4 errors gone away but occur new errors as `'ReportViewer1': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type` in ReportViewer1.aspx.designer.cs file , 

squiggly line in this `protected global::Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer ReportViewer1;
    }` line of above file
what should I do for this ?

Comment: You apparently have a method with the same name as the class that contains it somewhere in your project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070701/member-names-cannot-be-the-same-as-their-enclosing-type-c-sharp

Comment: but once I change the ReportViewer1 name I'm getting agin above 4 errors. I checked twice there is no any other place mention as "ReportViewer1" only follwing files ReportViewer1.aspx,  ReportViewer1.aspx.cs and ReportViewer1.aspx.designer.cs

Comment: No, you have a declaration in your project like this `public class MyClass { public void MyClass() {} }`. You need to find it and change the name of the method so it is not the same as the class. This error probably has nothing to do with the `ReportViewer`.

Comment: I'm not matured guy with these technologies, could you please tell me which file should i change in following 

1. https://dotnetfiddle.net/7T53ll  ---

2. https://dotnetfiddle.net/NDETad ---

3. https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ugXwS ---

Comment: Its this one: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ugXwS. You can't have a class named `ReportViewer1` with a control inside named `ReportViewer1`. But whether you change the class name or the name of the control, you need to change it everywhere in your project to make the compile errors go away. It might be easier just to delete the WebForm, start from scratch and use a different name for the class.

Comment: Now Im getting following error can you help me with that too  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453303/the-type-reportviewer-exists-in-both-microsoft-reportviewer-webforms-version?noredirect=1#comment52769061_32453303