# Binding Listview to property with same name as class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So I have a class `Question` with the properties `@Question` and `Answer` that is a string and I want to bind it to a Listview so that when I say

```
lv.ItemsSource = AllQuestions; //lv being the listview and AllQuestions being a List<Quesiton>
```

and in the XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" SelectionChanged="lv_SelectionChanged">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Questions" Width="225" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Question}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

it shows the `@Question` property. For example if I had

```
AllQuestions.Add(new Question { Quesiton = "why", Answer = 'a'});
lv.ItemsSource = AllQuestions;
```

The listview would show `why`, but instead it just shows white space. I have noticed though when I change `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Question}"` to `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Answer}"` it will properly show `a`.

If it helps here is the code to my question class:

```
public class Question
{
    public string @Question { get; set; }
    public char Answer { get; set; }
}
```

So to summarize, what  I want to know is how to display the `@Question` property and why when I have `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Question}"` it displays white space

[image: Example]

Comment: I can't even get your code to compile. Even with the `@`, I get CS0542. What version of the compiler are you using? That said, the basic problem here is that **your class is named wrongly**. If the type has both a "question" and an "answer", then "question" is the wrong name for the class. Or if you think that a "question" is something with an "answer" and something else, then "question" is the wrong name for the property. "Question" can't possibly be the right name for both the class and the property. Fix that and the other problem goes away.

Comment: Why don't you just rename your class or property? I tried to run your code and got the following error: "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type". I changed the property name to `Question1` in the class definition and in xaml then everything worked fine. Please see this answer for an explanation why you can't give the same name to property and class:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10070727/692829

Comment: @lena @PeterDuniho thanks for the responses. Obviously you're guys' suggestions worked, however I am still sitting here wondering why my code even compiled in the first place. I just ran the program and it worked fine, then changed `Question` to `Question1` and it worked, then changed it back to `Question` and it didn't work. Anyways if either of you would like to post your answer so I give you credit/make this post answered that would be good stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/hdhfk2xk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you can not have class member with the same name as the class.

> The members of a class or struct cannot have the same name as the class or struct, unless the member is a constructor.
>
> Error CS0542 might be caused if you inadvertently put a return type on a constructor, which in effect makes it into an ordinary method.

You need to rename your class or your property and don't forget to change the xaml file accordingly.