# CS0542 C# 'Something': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

My connect.xaml code:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="test.Views.Connect"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Connect Coming Soon!" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="105" Width="741" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT Bold"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I get the error CS0542 in Connect.g.cs:

> CS0542  C# 'Connect': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Post code directly into your question, not as an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070701/member-names-cannot-be-the-same-as-their-enclosing-type-c-sharp)

Comment: ok, i will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `Connect` is assumed to be the constructor, because it has the same name as the class. Since it's auto generated, it might be easier to just rename the class instead.