How can I get this function to work correctly?
class Program
{
    public void CheckEvenOdd(int i)
    {
        bool CheckEvenOdd = i % 2 == 0;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.CheckEvenOdd(0);
    }
   public static void Main2(String[] args)
    {
        int i;
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        Console.ReadLine();

        bool CheckEvenOdd = !(CheckEvenOdd = true);
        if (CheckEvenOdd) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number is even.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number is odd.");
        }
    }
}

Not sure how to get the function CheckEvenOdd to work. Very new to coding, so unsure that I am doing incorrectly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Why do you need Calculation class and Main2() method?  Program initiate its execution from Main() method present in Program class. Move code from Main2() to Main() method. It will work

Ok did as you said and it is not working getting this error 'CheckEvenOdd': member cannot be the same as their enclosing type...not sure what that means.
Thanks for your help btw

May be this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10070727/6299857

You don't have to make another main, you do your job on the main Main method.
and you don't have to make an instance of the class like this Program program = new Program(); because they are both in the same class and you can make it static
and the CheckEvenOdd should return a value to the main.
And you have to parse your input (which will be a string) to int.
note: make sure the class name isn't the same as any of its members (except the constructor of course).
like in the code:
using System;

class Program
{
    public static bool CheckEvenOdd(int i)
    {
        return i % 2 == 0;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        // You have to parse your input:
        int i = int.Parse(input);
        
        // the CheckEvenOdd() will return the value (which will be true or false) here:
        if (CheckEvenOdd(i))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number is even.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number is odd.");
        }
    }
}


Thank you, still getting this error though, no idea what it means or how to fix it. This error-  'CheckEvenOdd': member cannot be the same as their enclosing type...

I think you named the class as: CheckEvenOdd right?

Yeah, but even with your fixes I get the same error message.

It's because of the class name, change it.
